# date of birth search validation angularjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

while searching date of birth in frontend( `angularjs`) the request is going with different date of birth to backend spring

i am sending date of birth in this format:

```
Sun Aug 15 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

request url to backend:

```
dob=1999-08-14T18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: You have to add your frontend code, where you are parsing the date of birth and sending it to the backend. Otherwise we won't be able to help your with your problem!

Comment: improve code output

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date into the required format using the angular date filter, Have look here [AngularJS date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) .

You might be looking for something like this:    {{ date_expression | date : 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' : timezone}}